# Return but execute logic after it in a function?

Tags: javascript

I want getNum() to have the value, not console it within the function. If I do `return num[indexRandom]` in the function, the logic after that will break. Any clue?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var num = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
    var temp = [];
    $("button").on("click", function() {
        getNum();
    });

    function getNum() {
        if (num.length <= 0) {
            num = temp;
            temp = [];
        }
        var indexRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (num.length));
        console.log(num[indexRandom]); // instead of console how do return the value to the function
        temp.push(num[indexRandom]);
        num.splice(indexRandom, 1);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: Just add `return num[indexRandom]` at the end of the function?

Comment: Nah the splice will kill it. They need to store it in a temp variable and then return that

Comment: @AndrewL. it is not as simple as that

Comment: Where should `getNum` return value be returned to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value as the last line of the function after all other processing is done, but, as you may already realise, you can't just use `return num[indexRandom]` because the `.splice()` statement is removing that item from the array. So just use a temporary variable:

```
function getNum() {
    if (num.length <= 0) {
        num = temp;
        temp = [];
    }
    var indexRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (num.length));
    var selectedNum = num[indexRandom]);  // <-- add this
    temp.push(selectedNum);
    num.splice(indexRandom, 1);
    return selectedNum;                   // <-- add this
}
```

Alternatively, considering that the [`.splice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array containing the removed item, you could make use of that:

```
function getNum() {
    if (num.length <= 0) {
        num = temp;
        temp = [];
    }
    var indexRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (num.length));
    temp.push(num[indexRandom]);
    return num.splice(indexRandom, 1)[0];  // <-- note the [0] array access
}
```

Comment: Yep. Well...you don't "need" it given you can do it the second way without an extra variable. But either way is fine.

Comment: the second way is cleaner.

Comment: but why do u need to do this? `temp.push(num[indexRandom]);` ?

Comment: That part is from *your* original function. What it's doing is each time you call `getNum()` it removes a random item from the `num` array and adds that item to the `temp` array. Then, eventually when `num` is empty, it sets it back to what was in `temp` (that's what your `if` statement does at the beginning of the function). The idea is that that will randomly cycle through all the numbers in the array once without repeating any, then start again.

Answer (score 3):

I very strongly recommend not doing this. I would store `num[indexRandom]` as a simple variable, and return at the end, but if you are set in your ways, then use this:

```
try { //Return
    return num[indexRandom];
}
finally { //Code to run after returning. This will always happen after returning.
    temp.push(num[indexRandom]);
    num.splice(indexRandom,1);
}
```

Comment: try and finally is legit in javascript? I never see this before.

Comment: Yeah don't do this. Just use a temporary variable.

Comment: It is functional, but again, don't do it. Its a pretty hacky way of doing things and you should really just store it in a variable and return it afterwards

Answer (score 0):

There is the solution:

```
function getNum() {
    if (num.length <= 0) {
        num = temp;
        temp = [];
    }
    var indexRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * (num.length));
    var result = num[indexRandom];
    //console.log(num[indexRandom]);
    temp.push(num[indexRandom]);
    num.splice(indexRandom, 1);
    return result;
}
```